# A question about non linear sequence?

Tags: nt.number-theory

During my research, I come across this question.

Let $p=3^{101}-4$, $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n^3+1 \mod p$.

Is it true that $\exists k \in \mathbb N \cap [3,p-2], x_k=1$ ?

I have posted this question here : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3213569

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $p$ is prime and $\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=-1$, the function $f(x) := x^3 +1$ has the unique inverse and thus represents a permutation on $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. This means that starting at $x_1=1$ iterative application of $f$ should yield  $1$ again. The number of iterations equals the length of the cycle to which $1$ belongs in the permutation $f$.

It remains to notice that $f$ has one fixed point and one cycle of length 3 as established by [this PARI/GP code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrsDWOMzQw1DWx5uVK06jQtK2IM9Y2BHIKijLzSjQUlAvyc4ry80uKc_NTNEAKdCt0CjQVNHGqAKkhQhFYGVwdAFupJ9c=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). It follows that the cycle of element 1 has length $\leq p-4$ giving $k$ in the desired interval.

Btw, the inverse of $f$ can be stated explicitly as $f^{-1}(y)=(y-1)^{2\cdot 3^{100}-3}$.

Comment: So the answer is yes or no ?

Comment: Yes. What is unclear in my answer?

Comment: Why the length of the cycle can't be $p,p-1$ or $p-2$ ?

Comment: Length $p-3$ gives $k=p-2$ in the desired range, while length $> p-3$ is not possible. I'll add details in a moment.

Comment: Bravo. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Nice. Btw the same code says that $f^{\circ k}$ has only 1 or 4 fixed points for $k\le 9$, namely 4 iff $3|k$. Thus I don't know if the cycle containing zero has length $p-4$ (which would imply that $f^{\circ (p-3)}(0)=1$).

Comment: "Calculate  $\gcd(x^{2^{2024}}+x^{2024}+1,x^{2^{2023}}+x^{2023}+1)$" : I have give this challenge, but no one have found a justified answer.

Comment: @Dattier if your last comment is related to the post and discussion, please make it explicit.

Comment: @YCor  It was to propose another riddle of this type.

Comment: @Dattier well, comments is probably not the right place to do so.

Comment: MathOverflow is not intended for challenges.

Comment: @YCor: I've confirmed that there are no other cycles of length $\leq 12$.

Comment: I've further confirmed that there are no other cycles of length $\leq 15$.